# Can we show converenge for a variant of inverse dynamics controller?

Tags: control, stability, inverse-dynamics

I was wondering if it is possible to show that a variant of the inverse dynamics controller

$$\tau = \mathbf{M}(q)\ddot{q}^\mathrm{des} + \mathbf{K}_pe + \mathbf{K}_d\dot{e} + \mathbf{h}(q, \dot{q})$$

is able to stabilize the system

$$\mathbf{M}(q)\ddot{q} + \mathbf{h}(q, \dot{q}) = \tau$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is inspired by Ryszard Szwarc's answer in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509062/how-to-show-that-the-matrix-0-i-m-1k-p-m-1k-d-has-eigenvalues.

The dynamics of the system is in the form of
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})\ddot{\mathbf{q}} + \mathbf{h}(\mathbf{q}, \dot{\mathbf{q}}) = \tau
\end{equation}
and a variant of the inverse dynamics controller is in the form of
\begin{equation}
    \tau = \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})\ddot{\mathbf{q}}^\mathrm{des} + \mathbf{K}_p\Delta\mathbf{q} + \mathbf{K}_d\Delta\dot{\mathbf{q}} + \mathbf{h}(\mathbf{q}, \dot{\mathbf{q}}).
\end{equation}
Inputting the control into the dynamics gives us
\begin{align*}
    \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})\ddot{\mathbf{q}} + \mathbf{h}(\mathbf{q}, \dot{\mathbf{q}}) &= \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})\ddot{\mathbf{q}}^\mathrm{des} + \mathbf{K}_p\Delta\mathbf{q} + \mathbf{K}_d\Delta\dot{\mathbf{q}} + \mathbf{h}(\mathbf{q}, \dot{\mathbf{q}})\\
    \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})\ddot{\mathbf{q}} &= \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})\ddot{\mathbf{q}}^\mathrm{des} + \mathbf{K}_p\Delta\mathbf{q} + \mathbf{K}_d\Delta\dot{\mathbf{q}}\\
    -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})\Delta{\ddot{\mathbf{q}}} &= \mathbf{K}_p\Delta\mathbf{q} + \mathbf{K}_d\Delta\dot{\mathbf{q}}
\end{align*}
which can be written as
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \Delta\dot{\mathbf{q}}\\
        \Delta\ddot{\mathbf{q}}
    \end{bmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \mathbf{I}\\
        -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_p & -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_d
    \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q})}\begin{bmatrix}
        \Delta\mathbf{q}\\
        \Delta\dot{\mathbf{q}}
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
First, we show that $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q})$ is full rank, which leads to having non-zero eigenvalues. Using the property that elementary operations do not change the rank of a matrix, instead of investigating the rank of $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q})$, we look at the rank of
\begin{equation}
    \hat{\mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{q}) = \begin{bmatrix}
        \mathbf{I} & 0\\
        -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_d & -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_p
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Then, by using Schur's complement, we have
\begin{equation}
    \det\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}
        \mathbf{I} & 0\\
        -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_d & -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_p
    \end{bmatrix}\Bigg) = \det(\mathbf{I})\det(-\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_p) = \det(-\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_p).
\end{equation}
Using another property
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{rank}(\mathbf{C}\mathbf{D}) \leq \min\{\mathrm{rank}(\mathbf{C}), \mathrm{rank}(\mathbf{D})\}
\end{equation}
if we see $\mathbf{D} = -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_p$ and $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})$, then we have
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{rank}(-\mathbf{K}_p) \leq \min\{\mathrm{rank}(\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})), \mathrm{rank}(-\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_p)\}
\end{equation}
which leads to the conclusion that $-\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_p$ is full rank with a non-zero determinant. Then, we have $\hat{\mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{q})$ have a non-zero determinant and full rank, which finally gives us the conclusion that $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q})$ is full rank. We then have the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q})$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & \mathbf{I}\\
        -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_p & -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}\mathbf{K}_d
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        \mathbf{v}_1\\
        \mathbf{v}_2
    \end{bmatrix} = \lambda\begin{bmatrix}
        \mathbf{v}_1\\
        \mathbf{v}_2
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
with $\lambda \neq 0$, which gives us the relationship
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{v}_2 &= \lambda\mathbf{v}_1\\
    -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}(\mathbf{K}_p\mathbf{v}_1 + \mathbf{K}_d\mathbf{v}_2) &= \lambda\mathbf{v}_2
\end{align}
This also tells us that $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ cannot be zero vectors. If one of them is the zero vector, then both of them will be zero, which gives a trivial solution to the equation above. Inputting the first equation into the second gives us
\begin{equation}
    -\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})^{-1}(\mathbf{K}_p + \lambda\mathbf{K}_d)\mathbf{v}_1 = \lambda^2\mathbf{v}_1
\end{equation}
then, by multiplying $\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})$ on both sides, we have
\begin{equation}
    -\mathbf{K}_p\mathbf{v}_1 - \lambda\mathbf{K}_d\mathbf{v}_1 = \lambda^2\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})\mathbf{v}_1\quad\rightarrow\quad\lambda^2\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})\mathbf{v}_1 + \lambda\mathbf{K}_d\mathbf{v}_1 + \mathbf{K}_p\mathbf{v}_1 = 0
\end{equation}
then, if we multiply $\mathbf{v}_1^T$ on the left, we have
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:final_eq}
    (\mathbf{v}_1^T\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})\mathbf{v}_1)\lambda^2 + (\mathbf{v}_1^T\mathbf{K}_d\mathbf{v}_1)\lambda + \mathbf{v}_1^T\mathbf{K}_p\mathbf{v}_1 = 0.
\end{equation}
We know that all of the coefficients are positive, then from the quadratic root formula
\begin{equation}
    \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation}
we can determine all of the roots of the above equation have negative real parts.

Thus, we can show that $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q})$ is a Hurwitz matrix, which means the system of $\Delta{\mathbf{q}}$ and $\Delta{\dot{\mathbf{q}}}$ is stable. This tells us the controller $\tau$ can stabilize the system to zero error.

Comment: Nice work, is M(q) here the mass matrix in generalized coordinates? i.e. positive definite, symmetric?

Comment: Yes, the $\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})$ matrix is positive definite and symmetric, here $\mathbf{q}$ is the generalized coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

This would be too long for a comment, so I will add some work as an answer:

The proof of $A(\mathbf{q})$ being invertible is not perfect. First, add some structure to the $K_p$ and $K_d$ matrices. Assuming they are gain matrices, they should probably be positive definite and diagonal (thus invertible). In this case $M(\mathbf{q})^{-1} K_p$ and $M(\mathbf{q})^{-1} K_d$ are very easily shown to be full rank. $\text{det}(AB) = \text{det}(A)\text{det}(B)$. We also know that $M(q)$, $K_p$, and $K_d$ are all invertible and thus have nonzero determinant. To finalize the argument you could still use Schur's complement to show that $A(\mathbf{q})$ is invertible as $\text{det}(I)\text{det}(-M(\mathbf{q})^{-1} K_p)$ is nonzero.

To touch on adding structure to your variables before making arguments, there is technically no reason $\mathbf{v}_{1}^{T}K_{d}\mathbf{v}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{1}^{T}K_{p}\mathbf{v}_{1}$ would be guaranteed to be positive - unless you state it beforehand that $K_d$ and $K_p$ are positive definite! This may be well known to those familiar with PD control, but it is still good to explicitly mention this. Likewise, we do not know that $-M(\mathbf{q})^{-1}K_{p}$ is invertible as $K_p$ is not necessarily invertible unless some underlying assumptions are made.

As far as I can tell everything else looks good!